Issues with NativeWind classes in Expo Router with group and dynamic routes
I’m experiencing issues with NativeWind classes when using Expo Router, especially with group routes (e.g., (auth)) or dynamic routes (e.g., [post]).
The styles don’t apply properly or take effect only after multiple reloads.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
This is Welcome page
    const Welcome = () => {
  const image = require("../../assets/rb_5293.png");

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-neutral5">
      <Image source={image} style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }} />
      <Text className="text-neutral80 text-md font-pbold">Audio book App</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Welcome;

[![File and folder structure][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/EDI9JHJZ.png

